# PHP Как объединить повторяющийся товар и сплюсовать количество товара?

Tags: php

День добрый. Бьюсь не первый день над задачей...

Выводится товар в виде таблицы:

Название Код Количество

Через цикл foreach выводится повторяющийся товар в таблицу, но надо чтобы весь повторяющийся товар (по имени и коду) больше не выводился, а количество плюсовалось к тому что уже есть.

```
<?php foreach ($product_data as $product) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></td>
  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Вот мой код. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть?

**Обновление**

Мои попытки:

```
if(!in_array($product['name'], $sum)) { 
    $sum['name'][] = $product['name'];
}

if(!in_array($product['sku'], $sum)) {
        $sum['sku'][] = $product['sku'];
}  

$sum['name'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique( array_map("serialize", $sum['name'])));
        $sum['sku'] = array_map("unserialize", array_unique( array_map("serialize", $sum['sku'])));
```

Соответственно, `$sum` я объявил выше как массив. Собирает всё как надо. Остается 1 название, но как количество объединить одинакового?

Comment: Не вижу ни одного условия, где вы собираете новый собранный массив. Сами пробовали что-то делать?

Comment: Добавьте это в ваш вопрос, через "Править", не понятно что вы написали тут

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Александр, конечно, по вашему коду много не скажешь... Не понятно, откуда берется массив **$product_data** ... поэтому тяжело что более хорошее посоветовать.

1) Если вы этот **$product_data** забираете из базы данных, то можно спокойно поправить запрос и получать все значения, которые нужны... например, если у нас есть поля:

"id | name | quantity",

то мы можем забрать их так:

"SELECT id, name, SUM(quantity) as quantity_total FROM `mytable` GROUP BY id"

2) Если же вы имеете дело с только массивом, то его нужно предварительно подготовить перед выводом.

```
$product_data_new = array();
foreach ($product_data as $product) {
    if (!isset($product_data_new[$product['name']])) {
        $product_data_new[$product['name']] = $product;
    }
    else {
        $product_data_new[$product['name']]['quantity'] += $product['quantity'];
    }
}
```

ну а потом уже выводить ваш получившийся **$product_data_new**:

```
<?php foreach ($product_data_new as $product) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $product['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $product['sku']; ?></td>
  <td class="text-right"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

3) А вообще, по хорошему, лучше сразу фиксировать наличие такого товара в уже добавленных и увеличивать количество, а не добавлять еще один элемент массива.

Не претендую на изумительную красоту и изящность предложенных решений. Как поется в песне: "Думайте сами, решайте сами..." =)))

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте в запросе group by (наименование и код) а quantity выбирайте так: summ(quantity) as quantity. Но мне кажется, это как-то неправильно с точки зрения архитектуры бд

Comment: Почему-то не увидел варинат Станислава. Он предлагает то же самое, но группирует по id, а не по name.

Comment: тс написал, что группировать можно по имени или по коду =) в любом случае, я подписал, что мой ответ - это пример, о внедряя который еще нужно будет подумать, и, скорее всего, поправить, т.к. изначально мало вводных данных в вопросе

Comment: Да уже не важно, тс выбрал array_unique + array_map внутри array_map. Иногда аудитория этого ресурса поражает.

Comment: ilyaplot, спасибо Вам что откликнулись. По поводу того что я пошел через array_unique + array_map - то не осознанное действие и я не претендую на что-то. Просто это был один из вариантов, который нашел на просторах Рунета...
Простите если это как-то может Вас обидеть как программиста, т.к. я любитель и мой опыт на PHP весьма мал. С задачей такого типа я столкнулся впервые и старался сам выстроить логическую цепь, но как сделать в конечном варианте - не знал чисто с технической стороны.

Comment: Ваши решения меня лично никак не обидят. Просто подумайте, что получение данных в больших количествах, чем это требуется, а потом еще множественная циклическая обработка этих данных - это самый ресурсоемкий вариант. Хороший программист - ленивый программист. Учитесь писать как можно меньше как можно более оптимального кода.

Comment: Спасибо большое за наставления. Обязательно учту. Надо больше с массивами заводить знакомства и учить мат. часть :-)